# How to find text between two special html tags using html agility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to extract all texts between  and  in a webpage using html agility c#, but I didn't know what the xpath.

How to find text between this html tags:

```
<span class="a-title-heade a-step-one a-text-normal" dir="auto">
Science is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe
</span>
```

Comment: You might want to include a full structure of your HTML so that a valid XPath can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select nodes to select required node.

```
var html =@"<span class=""a-title-heade a-step-one a-text-normal"" dir=""auto"">Science is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe</ span > ";

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span").FirstOrDefault();

string name = node.InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Comment: Thank you, How to extract all texts if there is more than one text @shahraiz-kayani

Comment: Thank you, How to extract all texts if there is more than one text @shahraiz-kayani

Comment: your question doesnt make sense.. there is one text in that span.. what do you mean by all texts ? can you elaborate that in your question ?